# class exsheets automatic points by question and solution

Tags: exam, exercises, exsheets

I used the exsheets class for my exercises and exams and everything is very configurable but I have some issues with the dealing of points by questions...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}

\SetupExSheets[question]{print=true}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=true}
% Note in my version of exam : questions and solutions are not display in the same file => 2 pdf exam witch questions and corrections

% The solution with grading table is also not automatic...

\begin{question}% I want the total points computed automatically ?

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \addpoints{1}
    Question 1
    \item \addpoints{2}
    Question 2
  \end{enumerate}
  \currentpointssum*
\end{question}

\begin{solution}% I want the total points computed automatically ?
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \points{1}
    Question 1
    \item \points{2}
    Question 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \addpoints{3}
    Question II.1
    \item \addpoints{4}
    Quesion II.2
  \end{enumerate}
  \currentpointssum*
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \points{3}
    Question II.1
    \item \points{4}
    Quesion II.2
  \end{enumerate}
  \currentpointssum*
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

A solution is that you put manually the total by question but I am sure that there is a solution with automatic compute ?

Thanks you in advance.

Greetings.

Benoit

Answer (score 2):

This is actually rather easy with an up to date version of `exsheets`. The idea is this: define a new container (a box or rather coffin in l3) which holds the points of a question:

```
\DeclareExSheetsHeadingContainer{autopoints}{%
  \points{\GetQuestionProperty{points}{\CurrentQuestionID}}%
}
```

`\GetQuestionProperty` here needs two compilations for fetching the correct value.

Now use the new container (I called it `autopoints`) instead of the predefined `points` container in the heading instance in use. For the example below I copied the definition of the `block` heading as `myblock` and exchanged `points` by `autopoints`:

```
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myblock}{default}{
  join   = { title[r,B]number[l,B](1ex,0pt) } ,
  attach = {
     main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
     main[r,vc]autopoints[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
   }
}
```

Now all you have to do is use the new heading:

```
\SetupExSheets{headings = myblock}
```

Here is the complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{exsheets}[2015/11/18]% need v0.20

% define a new heading container which fetches the points of a question:
\DeclareExSheetsHeadingContainer{autopoints}{%
  \points{\GetQuestionProperty{points}{\CurrentQuestionID}}%
}

% define a variant of the `block' heading which uses the new container instead
% of the usual one for points:
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myblock}{default}{
  join   = { title[r,B]number[l,B](1ex,0pt) } ,
  attach = {
     main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
     main[r,vc]autopoints[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
   }
}

% setup exsheets to use the new heading:
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = myblock ,
  question/print=true ,
  solution/print=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \addpoints{1}
    Question 1
    \item \addpoints{2}
    Question 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \addpoints{3}
    Question II.1
    \item \addpoints{4}
    Quesion II.2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried to use this, but it throws a "Use of \??? doesn't match its definition." error in the first run of pdflatex. How can I get rid of this?